# twitter-bootstrap: how to get rid of underlined button text when hovering over a btn-group within an <a>-tag?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the markup below, the button text is underlined when hovered over. How can I get rid of that behavior?

Is there a better way to add links to a btn-group in bootstrap that avoids this behavior?

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn">Text</button>
        <button class="btn">Text</button>
    </div>
</a>
```

Tested CSS lines:

```
a:hover .btn-group { text-decoration: none }
a .btn-group:hover { text-decoration: none }
a:hover .btn-group .btn { text-decoration: none }
a .btn-group .btn:hover { text-decoration: none }
```

Any additional !important does not work, either (suggested by baptme).

Comment: How about css line "a:hover .btn-group { text-decoration: none }" ?

Comment: The line is still there. I also tried 
    a:hover .btn-group .btn
without success.

Comment: Try putting anchor tag inside <button> and adding a{display:block;}....it will work fine

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
{ text-decoration: none !important}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

For you example only `a{text-decoration: none}` will works

You can use a class not to interfere with the default behaviour of `<a>` tags.

```
<a href="#" class="nounderline">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Text</button>
    <button class="btn">Text</button>
  </div>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nounderline {
  text-decoration: none !important
}
```

Comment: I added !important to the four css lines mentioned above, but the underline still appears.

Comment: For better code readability, I would suggest `.no-underline` as I have no idea what a Nounderline is :P

Comment: You can do whatever you want with Nounderlines, plus they're very tasty

Comment: It still bugs me that this is the accepted answer... `<button>` inside of `<a>` is not legal html and `.btn` normally does not have an underline if used correctly.

Comment: `none !important` was needed to remove persistent underline.

Comment: You don't need to add !important, it's bad practice to add those everywhere. If you add more detail to the selector it will have a higher precedence than other selectors. `a.no-underline { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231843/4665736) works in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 154):

## Bootstrap 4+

This is [now easy to do](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/text/#text-decoration) in Bootstrap 4+

```
<a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
    <!-- That is all -->
</a>
```

Comment: simple but perfect!

Answer (score 18):

Buttons with the `btn` class do not have underlines unless you are doing something wrong: In this case nesting `<button>` inside of `<a>`<sup>†</sup>.

Something that I think you might be trying to do, is to create a bootstrap button without any decorations (underline, outline, button borders, etc). In other words, if your anchor is not a *hyperlink*, it is semantically a *button*.

<strike>Bootstrap's existing `btn` class appears to be the correct way to remove underline decorations from anchor buttons:</strike>

> Use the button classes on an `<a>`, `<button>`, or `<input>` element

**EDIT:** Hitesh points out that `btn` will give you a shadow on `:active`. Thanks! I have modified my first example to use `btn-link` and incorporated the accepted answer's `text-decoration: none` to avoid this problem. Note that nesting a button inside of an anchor remains malformed html<sup>†</sup>, a point which isn't addressed by any of the other answers.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <!-- use anchors for borderless buttons -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none">Text</a> 
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none">Text</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, for a regular button group using anchors:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
    <!-- use anchors for borderless buttons -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Text</a> 
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Text</a>
</div>
```

<strike>In other words, it should not be necessary to introduce your own `nounderline` class and/or custom styling as the other answers suggest.</strike> However, be aware of certain [subtleties](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#callout-fieldset-disabled-pointer-events).

---

<sup>†</sup> According to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), `<a><button>..</button></a>` is illegal:

> **Content model:**
>   Transparent, but there must be no **interactive content** descendant.

...

> **Interactive content** is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>   `a`, `audio` (if the controls attribute is present), **`button`**, `embed`, `iframe`, `img` (if the usemap attribute is present), `input` (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state), `keygen`, `label`, `object` (if the usemap attribute is present), `select`, `textarea`, `video` (if the controls attribute is present)

---

<strike>P.S. If, conversely, you wanted a button that **has** underline decorations, you might have used [`btn-link`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options). However, that should be rare - this is almost always just an anchor instead of a button!</strike>

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote? I put some time into thinking about this, adding references and answering in a helpful way; if I'm incorrect I'd like to know why! (additionally, I think that the other two answers are suboptimal or at least not idiomatic... I suspect that if no-underline was actually necessary it would already be included with bootstrap)

Comment: I did a pretty big revamp of my answer in the hopes that it will correct any misinterpretation I may have had about the original question. I hope this answer satisfies everyone.

Comment: I didn't spot that, thank you! I suppose .btn-link with the .nounderline suggested in the accepted answer is probably the way to go then...

Answer (score 13):

Why not just apply `nav-link` class?

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link">
```

Comment: there is padding around and link is display in block

Answer (score 7):

```
a.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're targeting the button, but it's the A Tag that causes the text-decoration: underline. So if you target the A tag then it should work.

```
a:hover, a:focus { text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: This worked for me by just adding one more thing : `a:hover, a:focus { text-decoration: none !important;}`    Thanks

Comment: it's typically not good practice to add !important on styles. I would try to add more specific selectors before resorting to using !important. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 4):

add the Bootstrap class `text-decoration-none` to your anchor tags

```
<a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn">Text</button>
        <button class="btn">Text</button>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Less or Sass with your project, you can define the `link-hover-decoration` variable (which is `underline` by default) and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

```
a:hover, /* OPTIONAL*/
a:visited,
a:focus
{text-decoration: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to  **remove the underline** from the anchor tag if you use bootstrap.
for my case, I used to like this;

```
 <a href="#first1" class=" nav-link">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">
   Reserve Table
   </button>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover{text-decoration: underline !important}
a{text-decoration: none !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.btn` is the best way, in modern website, it's not good while using `anchor element` without `href` so make the `anchor tag` to `button` is better.

Answer (score 0):

just  use bootstrap class "btn" in the link it will remove  underline on hover

Answer (score 0):

Add this **css** code to your css file:

```
a.btn { text-decoration: none !important; }
```

Use the **a** tag:

```
<a href="account/login" class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2">Login</a>
```

[image]