# bootstrap 4 remove underline when clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem removing underline that appears when clicking a menu in a navbar, this is the code that i use. but it is not working!

```
a.nav-link, a.nav-link:hover, a.nav-link:active, a.nav-link:visited, a.nav-link:focus {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

stil no luck.

> i'm using bootstrap 4 alpha

Comment: Post your HTML.

Answer (score 6):

you can remove underline in all a tag

```
 a, a:hover,a:visited, a:focus {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In bootstrap 4 you can simply add

```
.text-decoration-none
```

class and your job is done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading your css after bootstrap library?, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

In this case the css on style.css will prevail over bootstrap css

Let me know if that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

`Bootstrap 4` uses `Sass` for variables and mixins, the simplest way to override default behaviors of links is to define a custom class just like below:

```
.non-underline-link{
   text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

your html file:

```
<a href='/' class='non-underline-link'>
   <p>Hello!</p>
</a>
```

then recompile it in your project.
for more information go [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828829/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-get-rid-of-underlined-button-text-when-hovering-over-a)